# How to resolve stale element reference error : Element is not present in Page Document

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am automating my current project. In that am trying to click on the main menu.

For that below is my code

```
WebElement ul = driver.findElementByXPath(prop.getProperty("category"));
    List<WebElement> options = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    for(WebElement sample: options)
    {
        if(sample.getText().equals(data)){
            sample.click();
        }
    }
```

When I run this code the main menu is getting clicked and it gets loaded but still am getting Stale Element reference error exception. Help me to resolve this.

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element 
reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

**HTML code:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a **break** at the end of if statement

```
if(sample.getText().equals(data)){
            sample.click();
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the solution from the answer you have accepted as correct worked for you, I would suggest you to reconsider the logic of your code.

You do not need to iterate throughout the entire list for only looking up the element containing the text. **It is better to look up that element using for example xPath locator**.

This will let you to:

- save time for test execution
- avoid stale element exceptions

Comment: You are saying to give Xpath like this right?   Ex: //a[contains(text(),'data')]

Comment: Exactly. you only should build a proper string using the value that your data variable contains.